# timeNow.getTime() возвращает текущую дату больше необходимой

Tags: java

timeNow возвращает 1511422664873 что есть 29.01.49865 @ 00:07:53, но если написать так 1511422664(убрали три цифры) то действительно будет текущая дата.

Если выводить как `System.out.println("ПЛАНОВАЯ ДАТА:" + timeNow);`
То выводит текущую дату ТЕКУЩАЯ ДАТА:Thu Nov 23 10:43:09 GMT+03:00 2017

Почему timeNow возвращает дату больше ? Подскажите.

Вот часть кода.

```
private Date timeNow = new Date();

public Date getDifferentTime() {
    Date differentTime = new Date(plannedFlightDat.getTime() - timeNow.getTime());
    System.out.println("ТЕКУЩАЯ ДАТА:" + timeNow.getTime());
    return differentTime;
}
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста, как вы создаете plannedFlightDat

Comment: `1511422664873` - это значение в миллисекундах, которое как раз и соответствует дате `Thu Nov 23 10:37:44 MSK 2017`

Comment: Емае) Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Comment: timeNow.getTime() возвращает количество миллисекунд с 1 января, 1970, 00:00:00 по GMT. Тут все верно.

Comment: Благодарю !  Внимательнее буду читать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дата, возвращается в миллисекундах, вы же считаете, что это секунды, что не верно. Из-за этого и получается такое расхождение и необходимость убирать три цифры

Answer (score 2):

> 1511422664873 что есть 29.01.49865 @ 00:07:53

Это неверно.

Метод `getTime()` возвращает количество **миллисекунд**, прошедших с 00:00:00 UTC 01.01.1970.

Значению `1511422664873` соответствует `Thu Nov 23 2017 07:37:44 UTC`.